# AngularJS multiline Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select, multiline

Is it possible to make a select with multi-line options?

At the moment I have it so , but this does not work:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-ng-repeat="address in deliveryaddress" ng-model="selectedAddress">
        <strong>{{address.Firstname}}  {{address.Lastname}}</strong><br>
        {{address.Company}}<br>
        {{address.street}}<br>
        {{address.street2}}<br>
        {{address.street3}}<br>
        {{address.Zip}} {{address.City}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

A multiline Select with Bootstrap widout angular works:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
   <option data-content="First Line<br>Second Line">Mustard</option>
</select>
```

But with angular not:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option ata-ng-repeat="address in deliveryaddress" ng-model="selectedAddress" data-content="
        <strong>{{address.Firstname}}  {{address.Lastname}}</strong><br>
                {{address.Company}}<br>
                {{address.street}}<br>
                {{address.street2}}<br>
                {{address.street3}}<br>
                {{address.Zip}} {{address.City}}">
            </option>
        </select>
```

Have somebody an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I tried your example without Angular, but it doesn't seem to give me link breaks. Check this, https://plnkr.co/edit/8hgxhfU5mbUDpS9LSIKr?p=preview

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t0xicCode/454Lqbz8/
i have found this for bootstrap but in the datacontent i can't use the angular variables :-(

I think its works with bootstrapUI but i don't find a good  example

Comment: Have you looked at [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)?  You can definitely do this with it.  You could even put images in your select if you want!